# About the fifth gamma matrix

Tags: dirac-matrices

How can one prove that

$$\gamma^5=\frac{i}{4!}\varepsilon_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}\gamma^{\alpha}\gamma^{\beta}$$

from the following:

$$\gamma^5:=i\gamma^0\gamma^1\gamma^2\gamma^3=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will also need to know the anti-commutation relation of the gamma matrices:
$$\{\gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu \} = \gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu + \gamma^\nu \gamma^\mu = 2 \eta^{\mu \nu} I_4$$

Since the metric is symmetric in its indices, that will not contribute to the sum.

That means, swapping two gamma matrices introduces a sign flip. This is exactly what $\epsilon_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}$ does, and so each term will contribute the same (and so cancelling the $1/4!$).